# Touchpad controller for ps4

Tags: controllers

Can one use his/her cellphone (say android) as a gamepad for ps4 or XBox one?

I was thinking to buy a ps4 as a gift for a friend with disability but she can only use touchpad like cellphone or iPad.

Comment: The first question does not fit in our standards, I'm afraid. The second one is, so I will edit the first one out, so that maybe you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good news - Yes you can.

The PlayStation app (available on the play store or app store) allows you to sync a smartphone or tablet to your PlayStation 4 and use that as a controller. The process is fairly straight forward.

- Once you open your app, at the bottom of your screen you should be able to find a "Connect to PlayStation" option. If you are connected to the same wifi network with the PlayStation and the tablet/smart phone, the PS4 should appear on the list
- Next you will need to open the Settings in your PlayStation dashboard, and open the "PlayStation App Connection Settings". This will give you a code to into your tablet/phone, and you should be all good!

This video should provide some more detail for you:

This goes into a bit more detail about the functionality of it:

Comment: Mhhh... I see that you can control the PS4 with it, but can you also control the games?

Comment: @5pike yes you can :) - I'll add another link that goes into a bit more detail about the functionality

Comment: Very nice. Made my day(technically it's still night ;))

Comment: @user115964 Glad I could help! I hope your friend enjoys this!

Comment: pretty sure this depends on the game....